# ListFragment ошибка при создании

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

При запуске `Activity` вылетает ошибка. Ошибку найти не могу. Пробовал так же проверять через `path.isEmpty()`, но проблема не устранилась.

весь код:

```
public class FileManagerFragment extends ListFragment{

ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
String currentPath = "";
final private String TAG = "myTags";
private static final String KEY_LIST = "LIST";
private static final String KEY_PATH = "CURRENT_PATH";

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        paths.add("/storage/emulated/0/");
        paths.add("/storage/extSdCard/");
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.item,
                paths);
        setListAdapter(adapter);//Creating a primary form of application
    }
    else{
        currentPath = savedInstanceState.get(KEY_PATH).toString();
        paths = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(KEY_LIST);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.item,
                paths);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList(KEY_LIST, paths);
    outState.putString(KEY_PATH, currentPath);
}
```

}

текст ошибки

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.nikva.easyreading, PID: 8293
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2402)
                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1891)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:779)
                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1699)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2206)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2119)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/tvText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Пока вы не скажите что за ошибка, на какой строке и не покажите логи оной - как вам помочь? Одно только перечисление всех возможных ошибок займёт всё оставшееся время существования вселенной

Comment: Я добавил текст ошибки, и заметил вот что, когда я использую simple_list_item_1, то ошибки нет и все хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` не ожидает, что `TextView` будет обёрнут в `LinearLayout`. Либо измените макет так, чтобы он содержал только `TextView`, либо используйте другой конструктор:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.item, R.id.tv3, paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё что нужно для решения проблемы - вбить ошибку в поисковик

> https://www.google.ru/search?q=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+ArrayAdapter+requires+the+resource+ID+to+be+a+TextView&oq=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+ArrayAdapter+requires+the+resource+ID+to+be+a+TextView&aqs=chrome..69i57.622j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

и перейти по первой ссылке

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23020539/3212712

И увидеть ответ - адаптер ожидает, что переданная в него разметка содержит только `TextView`. У вас же он обёрнут в контейнер. Вам надо или удалить контейнер или использовать другой конструктор, в коий надо передать ID `TextView` из вашей разметки элемента:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.CUSTOM_LAYOUT_FOR_LISTVIEW_ITEM_NAME,
R.id.ID_OF_TEXTVIEW_IN_THIS_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, data);
```